# How to selectively start and end a persistent Apache::DBI for perl from the client/browser?

Tags: perl, dbi, apache-dbi

This question is related to our web-based application, which uses perl, apache, Apache::DBI and a database (MySQL, SQLite, or anything).

We know that Apache::DBI is used to create persistent db connections.  These connections live in memory from the time the Apache web server starts to the time it shuts down.

My Question is: Is it possible to create persistent db connections at any arbitrary time between the start and end of Apache process? We don't want to have persistent connections throughout the life of the Apache web server process.

We need to create persistent connections any time after the Apache web server is started. And we need to end persistent connections any time before the Apache web server is shut down.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not pretty sure about the way to do it.
But i would suggest to create a module, specifically to launch your connection, use
it, and end it.
Inside it you get your connection as a scalar, say $dbh, that will be common to everyone calling DBI functions (ùaking request to your mysql server).

```
package myBDDConnection;
use DBI;
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(&Query);

our $dbh = Connect();

sub Connect(){
my $dbh = DBI->connect(...);
...
return $dbh;
}
sub Query() {
 if(!$dbh) {$dbh=Connect()}
  //then perform query
}

sub Close(){
 $dbh->close() //or finish, i'm not sure
}
```

then, in your other modules, you import your myBDDConnection, and perform queries through the Query function from the previous module.

Comment: Hi Benzebuth, I think your solution will not create a persistent connection that can be available for few requests and responses between server and client.  I think the solution should involve Apache::DBI.

Comment: well... i think it does, if you use mod_perl and load the module at apache startup.
but i might be wrong

Comment: after investigating a bit, i found out that in the "solution" i gave, the db connection lives not throught the whole srever life, but through threads life. ie : some users may share some apache threads, thus sharing db connection. but where the thread is down (off), so is the db connection.